# Returning empty queryset in Django managers

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

How do you return an empty queryset in a Django manager?

```
class EventDateRangeManager(models.Manager):

    def occurring_in_day(self, year, month, day):
        try:
            picked_date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return an empty query set here

        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            start_day__lte=picked_date,
            end_day__gte=picked_date,
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the answer.

It's `return self.none()`.